# Stop System.Timers.Timer When Program Stops

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

I've been thoroughly researching this and haven't been able to find what I need. I am currently working in an asp.net website, code behind being vb.net, and using a timer from system.timers.timer. I have created a page with two buttons, one to start my timer and one to stop my timer. They work mostly as I expect them to.

Here is my question: How do I make the timer stop when my program/site stops running? Not when I exit the browser, but when the actual program running my site stops? For example, when this goes live the program will be running on our server. I want the timer to always run in the background once I've clicked start, unless the site goes down or I click stop. In my development environment, when I click run and click my timer's start button, I want the timer to run until I either click stop or I stop debugging. **The problem is that when I stop debugging the timer keeps running.** How do I stop the timer when I stop debugging or, when live, the website stops(crashes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to stop your timer you have to detect that your application is still running or not and for that you have to write code in your global.asax file.

on Application_end event or may be in Application_EndRequest

for view how to use Global.asax file please review this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228879/Global-asax-in-ASP-NET

Please check this and try this code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a task for a server side code: use `Global.asax` in this case